# Get element type of list type

Tags: python, python-3.6, typing

I have some list types (coming from `inspect.signature` -> `inspect.Parameter`) and I'd like to get to know the type of their elements. My current solution works but is extremely ugly, see minimal example below:

```
from typing import List, Type, TypeVar

TypeT = TypeVar('TypeT')

IntList = List[int]
StrList = List[str]

# todo: Solve without string representation and eval
def list_elem_type(list_type: Type[TypeT]) -> Type[TypeT]:
    assert str(list_type)[:11] == 'typing.List'
    return eval(str(list_type)[12:-1]) # type: ignore

assert list_elem_type(IntList) is int
assert list_elem_type(StrList) is str
```

What would be the correct way to get the type of a `List`'s elements?

(I'm using Python 3.6 and the code should survive a check with `mypy --strict`.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *believe* that you should be able to check the `__args__` parameter:

```
>>> from typing import Dict, List, Type, TypeVar
>>> List[Dict].__args__
(typing.Dict,)
>>> List[int].__args__
(<class 'int'>,)
```

But note from the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html):

> **Note** The typing module has been included in the standard library on a provisional basis. New features might be added and API may change
>   even between minor releases if deemed necessary by the core
>   developers.

So this probably isn't future proof.